# Copy-on-write и константные методы

Tags: c++

Есть вот такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

template<class T> class copy_on_write_ptr {
    private:
        shared_ptr<T> ptr;

        void detach() {
            T* p = ptr.get();
            if (p && !ptr.unique())
                ptr = make_shared<T>(*p);
        }

    public:
        copy_on_write_ptr(const copy_on_write_ptr<T>&) = default;

        copy_on_write_ptr(T* p) 
            : ptr(p) { }

        const T* operator->() const {
            return ptr.operator->();
        }

        T* operator->() {
            detach();
            return ptr.operator->();
        }
};

struct self {
    const self* ptr() const {
        return this;
    }

    self() = default;
    self(const self&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    copy_on_write_ptr<self> p1(new self());
    cout << p1->ptr() << endl;
    const copy_on_write_ptr<self> p2(p1);
    cout << p2->ptr() << endl;
    cout << p1->ptr() << endl;
}
```

Выполняю и получаю в консоли

```
0x4c5a10
0x4c5a10
0x4c5ba0
```

Почему в последнем случае получается другой адрес? Почему выполнился `detach`? Я же вызываю константный метод объекта. Ну как так-то?

Что можно сделать чтобы вызов константных методов не приводил к вызову `detach`? Понятно, что можно объявить `p1` константным и `detach` вызван не будет. Но задача поставлена так, чтобы вызов константных методов класса `self` не приводил к вызову `detach` даже если экземпляр класса `copy_on_write_ptr` сам по себе неконстантный.

Comment: Тут же есть и не константный вариант `operator->`, который вы и вызываете у неконстантного объекта. Сделайте два метода - `get` - возвращающий ссылку на константный объект  и `get_mutable`, возвращающий ссылку на неконстантный объекта (и потенциально создающий его).

Comment: Ну или аналогично STLным `begin()`, `begin() const` и `cbegin() const`.

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию для non-const lvalue выбирается оверлоад без const-квалификации.

> Что можно сделать чтобы вызов константных методов не приводил к вызову detach?

Ну, собственно, вызвать их как-то, заставив компилятор считать p1 константой:

```
template<class T> decltype(auto) invokePtr(T const &p) {
    return p->ptr();
}
template<class T> T const &constCast(T const &p) { return p; }

invokePtr(p1);
constCast(p1)->ptr();
const_cast<copy_on_write_ptr<self> const &>(p1)->ptr();
```

Comment: Дополню, что в C++17 есть `std::as_const`

Comment: @int3 Да, спасибо.